# What cloud solutions are there to connect different sites/branches?

Tags: security, file-transfer

I'm somewhat new to the field, but I have been tasked with coming up with the best way to connect remote customer sites to our two main offices. The data sent across from the customer to the main offices contains sensitive information and needs to be protected adequately. They are open to using the cloud, so I just need to figure a good way of doing this.

What cloud computing models would fit in this scenario and what are some examples of things that can be done in each (SaaS, IaaS etc.)?

Comment: Is the customer basically just sending you files?

Comment: @mikem Pretty much yes, nothing huge

Comment: Any reason you can use standard SCP/SFTP?

Comment: Sorry -- Any reason you "can't" use, SCP/SFTP?